# Failed command prompt in Slackware UEFI installation

Tags: linux, usb, grub, uefi, slackware

I am trying to install Slackware current while booting in UEFI mode. I am using a USB to boot the installation. To create the USB I downloaded the .iso from alienbob's website and ran `isohybrid --uefi slackware64-current-install-dvd.iso`. Then I followed the instructions here http://www.playwithtransistors.com/i...efi-boot-stick to create the bootable USB. I successfully boot in UEFI mode. However grub seems to cause some problems(apparently grub is used to boot the USB in UEFI). After I choose to boot from the USB in UEFI mode from the BIOS, grub presents me with choices what to boot: Slackware 14.2 huge.s or Slackware 14.2 huge.s (KMS console) or any installed operating system. Whichever of the first 2 options I choose, I am then presented with screen which requires to pick keyboard map. The keyboard seems to be messed up though as none of the keys seems to match its equivalent (e.g. I hit enter and 'a' is printed on the screen). How can I fix this. I wanna boot in UEFI mode. I also tried creating a bootable USB using `7z x slackware64-current-install-dvd.iso -o /run/media/niko/604A-00EA/` but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
1)Insert your USB without mounting. Use `fdisk -l` to find which device is it. Here we assume it's /dev/sdx. Run cgdisk /dev/sdx. Create two partitions: first one with size 100M and hex code EF00 and second one with all defaults (hex code 8300 and size the remaining size of the usb). You should now have 2 partitions /dev/sdx1 and /dev/sdx2
2)Format the partitions
`mkfs.vfat /dev/sdx1` (this will format in FAT32 the UEFI partition)
`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx2` (this will format in EXT4 the Linux partition)
3)Write the EFI partition

```
mkdir UEFI
sudo mount /dev/sdx1 UEFI
sudo mkdir UEFI/EFI
sudo mkdir UEFI/EFI/BOOT
```

Now follow the instructions for elilo from http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:slackware_admin:installing_on_uefi_hardware under the Creating your own install media for older Slackware releases section.

4) Write the /dev/sdx2 parition
`dd if=slackware.iso of=/dev/sdx2`

5)`umount /dev/sdx1`

You have a bootable Slackware USB in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires a Windows machine to create the USB installer.
An alternative solution, which helped in my case after failed installations following the steps is listed below:

1. Download the Slackware64-current ISO from [here](http://slackware.uk/people/alien-current-iso/slackware64-current-iso/).
2. Download Rufus (https://rufus.ie/). In my case I downloaded the portable version.
3. Create the USB stick with the "Partition scheme" UEFI and the downloaded ISO file.
4. On the machine with UEFI installation issues, disable "Secure Boot" in UEFI.
5. Boot the computer from the USB installation disk.
6. Create a UEFI partition (100 MB should be more than enough space).
7. Create your other partitions.
8. Run setup and install Slackware64-current.

Comment: This answer is good, despite the anonymous downvote. Not having a working linux is a perfectly valid starting point for installing Slackware...